# Why is the limit of e to the power of j*infinity equal to infinity?(EDIT: wrong assumption)

Tags: signal-processing

EDIT: I interpreted this step incorrectly. What I said below was never actually implied.

A solution to a homework problem for a free online Signals and Systems class I am trying to follow made the assumption that \$e^{j\cdot \infty}=\infty\$

Is there an explanation of why this would be infinity? I think this is implying that j*infinity is equal to infinity, and I am not sure why that is. Thank you.

Comment: That's not an electrical engineering question. I think it's not infinity. What problem it is and why it assumes it? It may be wrong or applies under specific conditions only.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not exclusively EE but more likely a math question.

Comment: say hello to your teacher and tell them they made a mistake when they wrote "\$e^{j\infty}\$", as quite clearly \$e^{jx}\$ doesn't ever converge for \$x\to\infty\$, so even under the laxest notational standards \$e^{j\infty}\$ simply doesn't exist; and that the claim that \$\lim_{x\to\infty } e^{jx} > 2\$ must be false, and that \$2\ll \infty\$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you cannot use infinity as you do in your equations. It's not a number and it doesn't make sense to write \$e^{j\cdot \infty}=\infty\$. Secondly, your claim is blatantly false.

$$e^{j\theta} = \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta) = a+jb, \ \ \ a,b \in [-1,1] $$

$$\therefore \lim_{\theta \to \infty} e^{j\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to \infty} \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta) = \text{undefined}$$

The limit is undefined as sine and cosine are periodic functions.

Comment: This isn't how limits work; in actuality, the limit works out to be undefined. It's still not infinite though.

Comment: Your last eqution is not true. Properly we say that the limit does not exist.